# how to convert multiple strings into list using python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to convert the strings into list using python. here is the values of a column

[View of the db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4We0e.png)

here is my string:

```
THERPET BASTHI BERIGAI ASTC-HUDCO KRISHNA-NAGAR TANK-STREET
```

I tried to print as list

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
print list(results)
```

But the output is

```
[(u'THERPET BASTHI BERIGAI ASTC-HUDCO',), (u'KRISHNA-NAGAR TANK-STREET',)]
```

Expected output is:

```
THERPET
BASTHI
BERIGAI
ASTC_HUDCO
KRISHNA-NAGAR
TANK-STREET
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, please follow @sachindubey 's solution if that is what you want. Or if you want to pull the records from db using cursor you can look at Matias Cicero answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split function and for loop to get answer

```
result = [(u'THERPET BASTHI BERIGAI ASTC-HUDCO',), (u'KRISHNA-NAGAR TANK-STREET',)]

for val in result:
   value = val[0]
   value = value.split(" ")
   for str in value:
       print(str)
```

**Output:**

> THERPET
>
> BASTHI
>
> BERIGAI
>
> ASTC-HUDCO
>
> KRISHNA-NAGAR
>
> TANK-STREET

Comment: I did that for string @Manjunath

Comment: @sachindubey `results` is not a `string` on OP's code, though

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, `results` seem to be a `sequence of tuples`.

First, let's get all the strings:

```
# You can either use the map function
results = map(lambda row: row[0], cursor.fetchall())

# Or list comprehension:
results = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Afterwards, join all the strings and then split them:

```
results = ' '.join(results).split(' ')
```

And finally, let's print:

```
print(results)
```

---

If you like one-liners:

```
print(' '.join([row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]).split(' '))
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code splits the string using `' '` as the delimiter. `x` then contains a list of words.

```
x = 'THERPET BASTHI BERIGAI ASTC-HUDCO KRISHNA-NAGAR TANK-STREET'
x = x.split(' ')
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This answer might or might not solve the issue the OP experience, so please always add an explanation to you answer to clarify how it might fix the OP's issue